# Multiple service activators of same input channel in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a requirement of processing the same information of a request in two different ways asynchronously. I am using spring integration in my project.
Can I have two service activators reading from the same input channel as below? I will get my data from a queue through an adapter and forwarded to the channel.

```
<int:channel id="dataChannel" />

<service-activator input-channel="dataChannel" ref="serviceA" method="method1">

<service-activator input-channel="dataChannel" ref="serviceB" method="method2">

<bean id="serviceA" class="a.b.test.ServiceA">

<bean id="serviceB" class="a.b.test.ServiceB">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `dataChannel` to

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id=`dataChannel` task-executor="exec" />
```

(declare a `<task:executor ... />`).